# Flagging all rows in an order that contain a particular item

Tags: excel, contains, powerpivot

I have a detailed list of all items in a handful of orders.  Each order has a unique identifier that appears in each relevant row.  I need a formula that can pull column C if any row in the order contains item X or column D if none of the rows in that order contain item X.  How can I do this?  I am happy to do this either directly in Excel or PowerPivot.

Thank you!

Comment: Filter > Copy/paste ?  Try recording a macro and editing the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DAX:

```
MyNiftyColumn=
IF(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            ALLEXCEPT('MyTable', 'MyTable'[OrderUniqueIdentifier])
            ,'MyTable'[Item] = "item X"
        )
    ) > 0
    ,'MyTable'[column C]
    ,'MyTable'[column D]
)
```

I refer below to function arguments positionally, with the first argument indicated by (1), the second by (2), and so on.

FILTER() steps row-by-row through the table in (1) and evaluates the boolean expression in (2), returning the subset of (1) for which (2) returns true.

ALLEXCEPT() returns the table in (1) with all context removed from it, except for the fields named in (2)-(n). Thus we return the entire table where [OrderUniqueIdentifier] is the same as on the current row.

FILTER()'s (2) just checks that [Item] is "Item X". Thus for each row we get a table that contains all rows sharing [OrderUniqueIdentifier] and having [Item] = "item X".

COUNTROWS() counts the rows in the table determined above.

We compare to 0. If > 0, then that order has some "item X", return [column C].

If 0, then that order contains no "item X", return [column D].

Comment: Thank you very much!!  This should do it!